# Node.Js + React.js + Flask web development architecture

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web

I am building a full stack web application. Currently, in my head, the way it would work is a flask api framework would be in charge of speaking to a database. Then a frontend would be built with Node.JS and React.JS would be built on this. However, from what I have found it seems like with React there may not be a need for Node. I guess my question is this, is Node necessary in this build framework or should React call the Flask backend? I am new to Node and React, so any tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you do in flask you can do in node.js with Express.js, going through node.js to contact the flask api doesen't make a lot of sense, because ur just using an api to contact an api that's already hosted on the same server, and therefore doesen't need something in the middle, either you use flask or node.js as backend, the choice depends on what you feel comfortable with the most, your use and expectations.